# Ignore duplicate calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I have the following sample daily production data, for which i have to calculate total processing time

```
  Date      Batch   Batch Code  Process time Changeover1 Changeover2 Total time
7-Jan-16    CBA6001  CBA            8           1           6          0
8-Jan-16    CBA6001  CBA            8           1           6          9
8-Jan-16    CBA6002  CBA            8           1           6          9
8-Jan-16    CBA6003  CBA            8           1           6          0
9-Jan-16    CBA6003  CBA            8           1           6          15
9-Jan-16    CBB6001  CBB            8           1           6          9
9-Jan-16    CBB6002  CBB            8           1           6          9
11-Jan-16   CBB6001  CBB            8           1           6          9
11-Jan-16   CBB6002  CBB            8           1           6          9
11-Jan-16   CBB6003  CBB            8           1           6          0
12-Jan-16   CBB6003  CBB            8           1           6          9
12-Jan-16   CBB6004  CBB            8           1           6          0
13-Jan-16   CBB6004  CBB            8           1           6          15
14-Jan-16   INA6001  INA            6           1           6          7
14-Jan-16   INA6002  INA            6           1           6          0
15-Jan-16   INA6002  INA            6           1           6          7
```

Example 2:

```
Date    Single batch    Batch Code  Cycle time  Atype   Btype MyFmla YourFmla
2-Mar-15    RFA5001       RFA          8           1    6       9      9
2-Mar-15    RFA5002       RFA          8           1    6       0      0
3-Mar-15    RFA5002       RFA          8           1    6       15     9
3-Mar-15    INB5003       INB          8           1    6       0      0
4-Mar-15    INB5003       INB          8           1    6       15     9
4-Mar-15    RTA5005       RTA          12          1    6       0      0
5-Mar-15    RTA5005       RTA          12          1    6       13     13
5-Mar-15    RTA5006       RTA          12          1    6       0      0
7-Mar-15    RTA5006       RTA          12          1    6       13     13
7-Mar-15    RTA5007       RTA          12          1    6       13     13
7-Mar-15    RTA5008       RTA          12          1    6       0      0
9-Mar-15    RTA5008       RTA          12          1    6       19     19
9-Mar-15    NZC5003       NZC           6          1    6       7      0
9-Mar-15    NZC5002       NZC           6          1    6       0      0
10-Mar-15   NZC5002       NZC           6          1    6       7      7
10-Mar-15   NZC5003       NZC           6          1    6       13     13
10-Mar-15   LBA5003       LBA           7          1    6       0      0
11-Mar-15   LBA5003       LBA           7          1    6       8      8
11-Mar-15   LBA5004       LBA           7          1    6       0      0
12-Mar-15   LBA5004       LBA           7          1    6       14     8
12-Mar-15   LBB5002       LBB           5          1    6       12     12
```

I have used the following formula for calculating the time and copied down to all the rows. The logic is simple

If there is a change in Product then add changeover2 to processing time (13, 14 Jan). If there is a change in batch of same product then add changeover1 to processing time to previous batch. And if a same batch is manufactured on different dates return zero (as there will be duplicates).

Now the issue is that, observe rows(6,7,8,9) you will find that the two batches are manufactured on those two dates. After applying the formula, observe row 6 and 8 they are both same batches but made on different date. Some times i do have three to same four batches of a product manufactured on two dates

Hence when I execute formula only one batch total time needs t be considered and rest should return 0

How can I rewrite the below formula to avoid duplicate calculation if batch is manufactured on different date

```
=IF(AND(LEFT(B2,3)=LEFT(B3,3),RIGHT(B2,4)<>RIGHT(B3,4)),(D2+E2+0),IF(AND(LEFT(B2,3)=LEFT(B3,3),RIGHT(B2,4)=RIGHT(B3,4)),0,IF(LEFT(B2,3)<>LEFT(B3,3),(D2+E2+F2),"")))
```

FYI Changeover1 is column E and Changeover2 is Column F

Comment: can you please also include the header row in your data above?

Answer (score 0):

This formula will check all cells both above and below for the same job/batch:

(You will need to update `B100` to whichever cell is the end of your data or extend it beyond the expected total size)

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(B2:B$100,LEFT(B2,3)&"*")>1,COUNTIF(B2:B$100,B2)=1),D2+E2,IF(COUNTIF(B2:B$100,B2)>1,0,D2+E2+F2))
```

It's hard to understand, was this what you are after or additional logic for if they both start on the same day?

[image: Example]

**Edit**

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF(D18:D$101,LEFT(D18,3)&"*")>1,COUNTIF(D18:D$101,D18)=1),F18+G18,IF(COUNTIF(D18:D$101,D18)>1,0,F18+G18+H18))
```

I tried this formula for the data you commented and got the expected result. Perhaps you didn't quite update all of the cell references correctly?

If you want less to update, consider using array formulas and named ranges. I won't have time to give an example of those today though as I have an all day conference starting in 5 minutes.

Comment: That was not my objective. Observe rows 6,7,8,9 in columnB. You will find that batch CBB001 and CBB002 are manufactured on 9th and 11th of Jan. In the corresponding rows the total time per batch is calculated for 4 batches but actually the time has to be calculated for only two batches. The formula i have used in total time column considers all the cases of change overs, except the above case. How to add this condition as well in excel?

Comment: So to clarify, your expected result is for row 10 to display 15 (`SUM(D10:F10)`)? as both CBB6001 and CBB6002 started on the same day? If you take a look at my example picture, the formula provided already does not count the first instance of both batches and only calculates for the last time the batch occurs in the column of data.

Comment: @rajendrakodavaty sorry forgot to tag you in the last comment

Comment: Your formula works fine. Can you tell me what is the significance of 100 in formula. I need to apply the formula various Manufacturing lines, hence the range changes. Can i use the same formula if there is change in range?

Comment: @rajendrakodavaty Yeah, 100 is literally just the end of the data. I wasn't sure how much data you were working with, so that just needs to be changed to reflect the longest data you might have. I'm gald it has worked, would you mind marking this as an answer using the tick to the left please?

Comment: Formula seems to work on some cells and for some it doesnot. Iam attching picture of the same. Column I is my formula and K is yours. Observe in row 5 there is a change in product, A type and B type and Standard Cycle time has to be added in this case. But here only Standard cycle time and A type changeover are added. [link]http://imgur.com/a/S954C

Comment: @rajendrakodavaty could you edit it into your question please? unfortunately imgur is blocked on the work systems.

Comment: @rajendrakodavaty Don't worry, accessed it on my phone

Comment: @rajendrakodavaty Edit made, please take a look. If you want 1 formula to work on all it gets rather advanced, I can achieve it but I don't have the time right now unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

When you have to compare some charachers on cells, I always avoid using "left", "right", "mid" inside "if" formula. Why? Because it makes the formula too long and sometimes hard to read.

Just make new column that contains of "left", "right", "mid" formula.
For ex: you can put the result of LEFT(B2,3) in H2 and RIGHT(B2,4) in I2 and so on

then... 
`=IF(AND(H2=H3,I2<>I3),(D2+E2+0), IF(AND(H2=H3,I2=I3),0,IF(H2<>H3,(D2+E2+F2),"")))`

but the problem is... that formula only comparing the upper cell and the bellow cell. well, it's better to use pivot for comparing all data. I use it all the time and it's easy enough because pivot always put the dupicate rows into an unique row.

By excluding "date" column, I think it's possible to avoid duplicates row. Please see [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c7qyNLoC3zxgTqCfmlB6HoRwBwHmjB6Q057BLNYj6Z0/edit?usp=sharing) in sheet "duplicate".
unfortunately... google spreadsheet can't use pivot, so I can't make the process, only the final result.

Comment: I cannot use pivot in this case, because i am not trying to sumup the values with same batch code. At every occurrence of a batch there will be addition of total time. My objctive is to make excel return zero when the same batch is manufactured on different date.I have provided the example above, please review it

Answer (score 0):

I think this one should work for you

```
=IF(A2=LOOKUP(1,0/($B$2:$B$17=B2),$A$2:$A$17),IF(C2=C3,D2+E2,IF(C2<>C3,D2+E2+F2)),0)
```

If you are adding new rows to the table regularly, you might want to make the length of the range flexible by replacing $B$17 with a `INDEX/COUNTA` combination like this:

```
=IF(A2=LOOKUP(1,0/($B$2:INDEX($B:$B,COUNTA($B:$B))=B2),$A$2:INDEX($A:$A,COUNTA($A:$A))),IF(C2=C3,D2+E2,IF(C2<>C3,D2+E2+F2)),0)
```